# How can i get a 'rcom' package?

Tags: r, install.packages

When I tried executing this
`install.packages("rcom")`
I got warning
`package ‘rcom’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)`

I also tried this
`install.packages(c(, "rcom"), repos = "http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download", lib=.Library)`
and i got this as warnig
`Warning: unable to access index for repository http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download/bin/windows/contrib/3.1`
Warning message:
`package ‘rcom’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)`

Comment: Have you looked into RDCOMClient? http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMClient/

Comment: Yes i tried but still i am getting  error
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.1

   package ‘RDCOMClient’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RDCOMClient’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

Comment: `install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type = "source")` worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Just run that command:

```
install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R", type = "source")
```

Source:

http://www.omegahat.net/RDCOMClient/

Comment: That's awesome. Join us in [R Public Chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public) whenever you are free to help others!

Comment: @BhargavRao Nice, I wasn't aware public chatrooms even existed on SO... Thanks for the invitation, I'll make sure to visit from time to time!

Comment: Looks like Omegahat has moved to omegahat.net. The .org page goes to a blank hosting page now.

Comment: I just tried to install the package from source using the command above, but it fails to build (I run R 3.5.3). There are a lot of warnings but this seems to kill it: `COMError.o:COMError.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTV10RCOMObject[.refptr._ZTV10RCOMObject]+0x0): undefined reference to 'vtable for RCOMObject' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status no DLL was created ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RDCOMClient'` Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: In case anyone has the same problem as that which I described above: I solved it by running **`devtools::install_github('omegahat/RDCOMClient')`** instead of `install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R", type = "source")`

Comment: On windows this worked for me `install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R", type = "win.binary")`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a suitable version of R installed, the following steps are necessary to install RExcel and the infrastructure. You need to be logged into Windows with administrator privileges to do this!

It is very important that the installed version of R wrote its entry to the registry. If you have R installed without this registry entry, RExcel will not work. You need to reinstall R in that case. When reinstalling R all the packages will be retained, but any changes in the system wide profile (set in etc/Rprofile.site) will be lost.

You also need to follow these instructions if you upgrade R, i.e. you install a new release of R after you have installed RExcel.
Download the statconn DCOM server and execute the program you downloaded
Start R as administrator (on Windows 7 and later you need to right-click the R icon and click the corresponding item)

In R, run the following commands (you must start R as administrator to do this):

```
options(install.packages.check.source = "no")

install.packages(c("rscproxy","rcom"),repos="http://www.autstat.com/download",
                 lib=.Library,type="win.binary")

library(rcom)

comRegisterRegistry()
```

Now you have rcom installed, but RExcel is not installed yet.
To install RExcel for 32bit Excel: download the RExcel installer and run this installation program. To install RExcel for 64bit Excell: download the RExcel installer and run this installation program. Installing RExcel this way will set the background server of R as the default R server for RExcel. You can change this in the configuration settings in R. If you want to set the foreground server as the default site wide server, there is an appropriate option in one of the dialogs of the installation.

[Source](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/erich.neuwirth/php/rcomwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install)